# Add Comma in the field

Tags: mysql, sql, nested, sql-update

i have data like

```
Table1-> Name, point, North,Souht,West
```

> `sae,[empty],N,S,W`

I want to fill `point` with query because too many data to add it manualy, but I have problem with 'comma'

what U want is `point-> N,S` or `point-> S` 

and what ive done is `point->NS` or `point-> ,S`

with is the best way to doit using the concat or union all? or else,

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`concat_ws`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) function:

```
UPDATE table1
SET    point = CONCAT_WS(',', north, south)
```

Comment: its work, but i have many many extra coma with that code, any other idea or how to use it when the value is empty.?